# How can I get rid of printer drivers I accidentally installed on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, printer, updates, uninstall

I was trying to connect to a Canon ImageRunner at one of my client's workplace, and an HP printer at a different client's worklplace. Most times my Mac can find and install printers with no problem. However, these were rather new network printers and I suppose it was not in the included drivers.

I installed both the HP and the Canon printer drivers on different days, using the install package. I then deleted the applications that they installed from the `Applications` folder by dragging them to the trash and emptying it.

Looks like the software might have had an uninstaller program but I am not even sure which one I installed. Oops.

Now when software update pops up it wants me to update Lexmark and HP Printer software.

[image]

I really want these two to go away - I really don't want to install updates for them. How can I make them go away?

For extra points, how can I remove other remnants of these? Perhaps by checking the `launchd` config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to play with *pkg-util* I think. For example,

```
$ pkgutil --pkgs | grep -i hp
com.adobe.pkg.FlashPlayer
com.apple.pkg.HP_CHorse
com.apple.pkg.HP_CHorseD
com.apple.pkg.HP_CHorseI
com.apple.pkg.HP_CHorseIL
com.apple.pkg.HP_CHorseL
com.apple.pkg.HP_Chuckwalla
com.apple.pkg.HP_Cmd2HP
com.apple.pkg.HP_DesignjetIO
com.apple.pkg.HP_DMF
com.apple.pkg.HP_Fax2
com.apple.pkg.HP_ImageEnhancement
com.apple.pkg.HP_Inkjet8
com.apple.pkg.HP_Inkjet9
com.apple.pkg.HP_PDE
com.apple.pkg.HP_Pdf2Pdf1
com.apple.pkg.HP_Pdf2Pdf2
com.apple.pkg.HP_PS
com.apple.pkg.HP_Scan
com.apple.pkg.HP_Scan3
com.apple.pkg.HP_SmartX
```

You can see the files owned by a package like this:

```
~ $ pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.HP_DesignjetIO
System
System/Library
System/Library/Extensions
System/Library/Extensions/hp_designjet_series.kext
System/Library/Extensions/hp_designjet_series.kext/Contents
System/Library/Extensions/hp_designjet_series.kext/Contents/Info.plist
System/Library/Extensions/hp_designjet_series.kext/Contents/version.plist
~ $ pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.HP_PDE
Library
Library/Printers
Library/Printers/hp
Library/Printers/hp/PDEs
Library/Printers/hp/PDEs/PDE.plugin
Library/Printers/hp/PDEs/PDE.plugin/Contents
Library/Printers/hp/PDEs/PDE.plugin/Contents/Info.plist
[...]
```

So do *pkgutil --forget* on the packages you don't want, and presumably that will stop updates (**untested**). You can also delete the files it lists, carefully (**untested**).